# coroutine callback when running job is longer than 10 seconds

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

this is weird when coroutine itself was born to reduce callback

well, i didn't found any related questions, but please mention here if any

let's say i have this code

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    hitApi()
}
```

i would like to have a callback when method `hitApi()` is taking longer than 10 seconds, so the activity would call some action like

```
onHitApiLongerThanTenSeconds() {
    showToast("hit api is taking longer than expected")
}
```

so... is it possible?

i know there's `measureTimeMillis` method but the value is returned after the job is done, cmiiw.

thanks in advance

[edit]

i don't want `hitApi` method is cancelled when the callback was called, just continue the process until i got the response or reach general maximum timeout like 30s or 60s

Comment: Is `hitApi` a blocking function or a proper suspend function?

Comment: @Tenfour04 it's a suspend function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this would work (didn't test):

```
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        supervisorScope { // or coroutineScope
            val toastJob = launch {
                delay(10000L)
                showToast("hit api is taking longer than expected")
            }
            hitApi()
            toastJob.cancel()
        }
    }
```

Comment: i didn't see that coming :') , so it's using supervisor scope. well tested and works as expected. thanks for your solution!

Comment: `coroutineScope` should be fine too as long as you aren't launching multiple children coroutines that should be cancelled independently.

Comment: You don't need `withContext` in there, the dispatcher is already `Main`. Also, `supervisorScope` shouldn't be needed, explicitly cancelling a coroutine doesn't cause the parent to get cancelled (as far as I remember).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik True, I'll remove the withContext.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your call with a `withTimeout` block. It will throw a `TimeoutCancellationException` if its block takes longer than its argument.

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    try {
        withTimeout(10_000) {
            hitApi()
        }
    } catch (e: TimeoutCancellationException) {
        onHitApiLongerThanTenSeconds()
    }
}
```

Or if you expect a value returned from `hitApi` method you can use a `withTimeoutOrNull` which will return `null` if its block takes longer than its argument:

```
val value = withTimeoutOrNull(10_000) {
    hitApi()
}

if (value == null) {
    onHitApiLongerThanTenSeconds()
}
```

Comment: thanks. actually i would like to continue the `hitApi()` process when callback was called, but your solution probably cancel the `hitApi()` process, am i correct? maybe i should edit my question to make it clear